# Unresolved reference: androidTarget

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am new to KMM. Recently I'm working to builda a Note app usiing KMM. So, after completing the project I'm facing this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0RKn.png)

My build.graadle.kts(:shared) file

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
    id("app.cash.sqldelight") version "2.0.0-alpha05"
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget()
    //android()

    jvm("desktop")

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach { iosTarget ->
        iosTarget.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.runtime)
                implementation(compose.foundation)
                implementation(compose.material)
                @OptIn(org.jetbrains.compose.ExperimentalComposeLibrary::class)
                implementation(compose.components.resources)
                //implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:1.5.3")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.4.0")
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
                api("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
                api("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1")
                implementation("app.cash.sqldelight:android-driver:2.0.0-alpha05")
                //implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:1.5.3")
            }
        }
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            dependencies{
                //implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:native-driver:1.5.3")
                implementation("app.cash.sqldelight:native-driver:2.0.0-alpha05")
            }
        }
        val desktopMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.desktop.common)
            }
        }
    }
}
sqldelight {
    databases {
        create("NoteDatabase") {
            packageName.set("com.myapplication")
        }
    }
}


android {
    compileSdk = (findProperty("android.compileSdk") as String).toInt()
    namespace = "com.myapplication.common"

    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    sourceSets["main"].res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
    sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = (findProperty("android.minSdk") as String).toInt()
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }
}
```

My build.gradle.kts(:androidApp)

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget()
    sourceSets {
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(project(":shared"))
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = (findProperty("android.compileSdk") as String).toInt()
    namespace = "com.myapplication"

    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.myapplication.MyApplication"
        minSdk = (findProperty("android.minSdk") as String).toInt()
        targetSdk = (findProperty("android.targetSdk") as String).toInt()
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    compileOptions {
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }
}

dependencies{
    implementation(project(":shared"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1")
    coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.4.0")

    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.45")
    "kapt"("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
    "kapt"("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")
}
```

And root level build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    // this is necessary to avoid the plugins to be loaded multiple times
    // in each subproject's classloader
    kotlin("multiplatform").apply(false)
    id("com.android.application").apply(false)
    id("com.android.library").apply(false)
    id("org.jetbrains.compose").apply(false)
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
}
```

I've commented out 'androidTarget()' and used android() but that gave me another error odf depreciated gradle features. Now please provide me a solution

Comment: Your Android app shouldn't have `kotlin("multiplatform")` setup. It's pure Kotlin/android project. Fix that and re-try things. Maybe something will work out. Try creating a new Kotlin multiplatform app through Android Studio Project wizard and compare that structure with yours.

Comment: I have cloned the git repository from here https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform-template . There it was this way. Should I try Kotlin("Android") everywhere?

Comment: oh didn't realize you're doing compose multiplatform app. So git repository is giving you error right after cloning without any changes? In that case, I can look at the repository code and see if I find something obvious

Comment: The git repo I had cloned was bit older. Then I cloned from this repo https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform-ios-android-template/#readme . after that it also gave me same error so I switched to "android()" and found that dagger-hilt is not compatible with this version. So then I used Koin for dependency Injection. It resolved. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 3):

In my case when I got this error:

[image]

I realized I had added **sqlDelightGradlePlugin** to **build.gradle.kts(:shared)**

```
plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
alias(libs.plugins.kotlinCocoapods)
alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
alias(libs.plugins.kotlinxSerialization)
alias(libs.plugins.sqlDelightGradlePlugin)
}
```

But I did not add classpath to **build.gradle.kts(:MyAppName)**

```
    //trick: for the same plugin versions in all sub-modules
    plugins {
    //trick: for the same plugin versions in all sub-modules
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinCocoapods).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinxSerialization).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinParcelize).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.sqlDelightGradlePlugin).apply(false)
}
```

**So you have to recheck your plugins when you added them to the project and it might be helpful.**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in the root level build.gradle.kts, I explicitly added a version and the error went away.

`kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.9.0").apply(false)`

Comment: Not in this case but I used this solution in another case before and it worked. Maybe it will work in this case also.